# Sonar "Remove this unused import 'java.util.List'" with record

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-17, java-record

We use record like this:

```
package com.package.name;

import java.util.List;

public record RecodName(String type, List<String> data) {}
```

But we get a Code smell that says:

```
Remove this unused import 'java.util.List'.Why is this an issue?
```

Sonar Version 8.9.8

Is there any way to avoid this?
Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you specify the Java version in the Sonar configuration to be at least Java 16?

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueHupner Yes, we use the latest version, beside, we don't have any problem with other features of java-17

Comment: It appears this bug was fixed, see [SONARJAVA-3799](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3799). I am not very familiar with SonarQube, but to me it sounds like SonarJava (plugin) version is not the same as SonarQube version. You might be able to fix this by updating the SonarJava plugin.